# Ways to remove trailing commas

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to send to a `.txt` file in `JSON` format an array of pairs of a password in a `hashlist` and how often they appear in it. I will then use it to produce charts. The charts require that the `JSON` data be in the following format:

```
[["patches90",35],
["Champions17",32],
["scotty1977",29],
["Kiddos08",25],
["holidays2016",21],
["scott26me",17],
["People1123@",13],
["Software0)",9],
["Artistic104",5],
["bank123",2]]
```

I'm using this code:

```
    f = open('/var/www/html/hashtopussy/top10.txt', 'w')
    f.print "["

    @words.sort{|a,b| (a[1]<=>b[1]) * -1}[0, @cap_at].each { |elem|
        percentage = (elem[1].to_f / @total_words_processed) * 100
        ret_str << "#{elem[0]} = #{elem[1].to_s} (#{percentage.round(2).to_s}%)\n"

        #my code goes here

        f.print  "[#{elem[0].to_json},#{elem[1].to_json}]"
        if (elem != elem.last) 
            f.print ",\n"
        else f.print "]"
        end

        #and ends here
    }

    #f.print "]\n"
    f.close
```

The chart I'm creating is within a Modal. the `var dataPoints` section is where the file is being written to by the above ruby code. My code produces:

```
[["patches90",35],
 ["Champions17",32],
 ["scotty1977",29],
 ["Kiddos08",25],
 ["holidays2016",21],
 ["scott26me",17],
 ["People1123@",13],
 ["Software0)",9],
 ["Artistic104",5],
 ["bank123",2],
```

I have an extra comma in `["bank123",2],` and a missing closing bracket `]` at the end. I tried multiple loops and conditions with no luck.

Comment: I am _pretty_ sure that if you prepare your array, call `.to_json` on it and render, chart js will accept it just fine.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you show me what that would look like please?

Comment: I can, if you post a [mcve]

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I edited the original question, is that what you were looking for? Sorry, once again, i'm new to all this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev oh, i think it's also important to note that i'm using Canvas JS, not chart js. http://canvasjs.com/

Comment: No, not that at all. Chart code is irrelevant. I meant that your first snippet needs to be changed in such a way (or new snippet posted) that I (or anybody) can copy-paste-run it and get _the same results_ ("complete" and "verifiable" parts). Main issue with the current snippet: it uses unknown variables.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev.. i can try to post the full script if you'd like.. i'm editing a hashlist analyzer called Pipal.. the source code can be found on github. https://github.com/digininja/pipal i'm editing the "basic.rb" page. i didn't originally post the full script due to it's enormous length, i apologize.

Comment: yep, we don't need the full script either. Only the _minimal_ amount, just barely enough to satisfy _complete_ and _verifiable_ requirements.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev here's a direct link to the file i'm editing: https://github.com/digininja/pipal/blob/master/checkers_available/basic.rb

Comment: i believe the link i just posted should be close to what you're looking for, aside from that.. i'm not sure if you could meet the complete and verifiable requirements without the whole program..

Comment: Let's step back. What is the problem you're having? You have a data structure, which you iterate and build a string (persisted in a file, which is also kind of irrelevant, but I'll accept that) and that string ends up having one too many commas than needed. Correct? Can you edit your original snippet  by hardcoding needed data and removing irrelevant stuff? Remember, the goal is copy-paste-run-see.

Comment: By the way, the ability to break big problems into smaller, _isolated_ sub-problems is a fundamental skill for programmers. Without it, you just can't build anything but the simplest things (which are not big enough to warrant decomposition).

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by hand. Use the [JSON](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

You want to serialize an array of arrays. You're given an example of the JSON, so the question is, what structure do you need to generate to pass to the [JSON](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) serializer to get that desired result:

```
require 'json'

foo = JSON[
'[["patches90",35],
["Champions17",32],
["scotty1977",29],
["Kiddos08",25],
["holidays2016",21],
["scott26me",17],
["People1123@",13],
["Software0)",9],
["Artistic104",5],
["bank123",2]]'
]
```

At this point `foo` is the equivalent object:

```
foo
# => [["patches90", 35],
#     ["Champions17", 32],
#     ["scotty1977", 29],
#     ["Kiddos08", 25],
#     ["holidays2016", 21],
#     ["scott26me", 17],
#     ["People1123@", 13],
#     ["Software0)", 9],
#     ["Artistic104", 5],
#     ["bank123", 2]]
```

(In this case the parsed object looks like the original JSON string, but that's not always true.)

You can test this by starting with a Ruby object and try serializing it:

```
require 'json'

foo = [
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', 2]
]

puts JSON[foo]

# >> [["a",1],["b",2]]
```

So, build an array of two-element arrays and pass it to JSON and save that output. I'd typically use something like:

```
File.write('foo.json', JSON[foo])
```

This tactic makes it easy to unravel any JSON API response into a Ruby object, possibly modify it, and reserialize it:

```
foo = JSON['{"a":1,"b":2}'] # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
foo['c'] = 4
puts JSON[foo]       
# >> {"a":1,"b":2,"c":4}
```

In short, use the existing well-tested wheel.